# Unable to open powerpoint presentation in Microsoft PowerPoint iPad Application from a Web URL by using Url Scheme from iOS application

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ipad, powerpoint

I am Building  an iOS application which contains PowerPoint presentations,  these presentations are stored on the server side. When the user selects a presentation from my application, it need to open in PowerPoint iPad Application. I used URL scheme of powerpoint iPad Application to pass the url of the selected presentation. But PowerPoint in iPad always showing:

> "The Server you are trying to access is not supported by this version of Office."

```
let urlString = "ms-powerpoint:https://kahanicloud.com/CustomPresentation/Download?id=58006a40775efb09d0200659&parentId=system-all-files&fileName=shared.pptx"
let  DocUrl = URL(string: urlString)
let canOpen = UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(DocUrl!)
if canOpen
{
   UIApplication.shared.openURL(DocUrl!)
}
```

I tried the above Swift code to achieve this, but failed.

Answer (score 0):

You are not providing enough parameter to Url schema.try following:

```
ms-powerpoint:ofe|u|https://kahanicloud.com/CustomPresentation/Download?id=58006a40775efb09d0200659&parentId=system-all-files&fileName=shared.pptx|a|App
```

You can get more detail of required parameter from [here](http://wopi.readthedocs.io/projects/officewopi/en/latest/scenarios/from_app.html)